# allow for a single alpha character at the start of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have this pregmatch which allows for only numeric characters but i need to allow for the potential of one alpha character at the start of the string such as

T17900

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^0-9\s]/", "", $value);
```

EXAMPLE:

IF this is my $value = 22202-HAV.jpg

I need only **22202.**

If this is my $value = T22202-HAV.jpg

I need only **T22202**

Comment: a good testing website for RegExp -> http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $value = preg_replace('~^([a-z][0-9]*|[0-9]+)?.*~i', "$1", $value);
```

basically, if the string starts with a letter + some digits or just digits, keep this part and delete the rest.

Comment: Using `/[a-z]/i` to get a letter only works on 7-bit datasets, and is somewhat deprecated.  You can use `/\pL/` to get a single letter, or `/\pL+/` to get several of them in a row, and this works on 7-bit data too.

Answer (score 0):

`$value = preg_replace("/^[A-Z][0-9]*/", "", $value);` ^ is for position = start

Comment: Add a question mark after the [A-Z] if that alpha character is optional.

Comment: This unfortunately doesnt work

As if you have a filename like 22201-HAV.jpg all the bits on the end are left.

I need it to leave 22201 or if for any reason there is a letter at the start that will be left too.  IE T22201

Comment: @Andy .. perhaps you could have added some more detail to your question -or maybe added an example !

Comment: @CodeTwice the question mark after those brackets looses the first number in my filename.

Comment: @Andy - so you need to remove the "-" and everything after it in a file name is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in this case, but [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead:

```
<?php
foreach(array('22202-HAV.jpg', 'T22202-HAV.jpg') as $value) {
    if (preg_match("/(?P<name>(?:\A[[:alpha:]])?[0-9\s]*)/", $value, $match)) {
        $value = $match['name'];
    }
    echo $value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

See it [`in action`](http://ideone.com/E3hjL)

And I don't understand why you need this `\s` in your pattern, but since it's there, I've added it to my answer code as well